# Invalid Next Control Variable

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I am hitting a wall with the error "Compile Error: Invalid Next Control variable reference".
Trying to skip code lines if the variable is not found in the sheet, e.g if X = 0 then skip. Can't debug step by step since it jumps straight to the error.

appreciate any 2 cents

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim D As Integer

'{.......}

' a
Freight_Str_Minimum_List(1) = strFreightperMinCol:
Freight_Str_Minimum_List(2) = strFreightMinCol:
Freight_Str_Minimum_List(3) = strMOtherMinCol

' b
Freight_Col_Minimum_List(1) = FreightperMinCol:
Freight_Col_Minimum_List(2) = FreightMinCol:
Freight_Col_Minimum_List(3) = MOtherMinCol

' d
Freight_Str_PerKg_List(1) = strFreightperKgCol:
Freight_Str_PerKg_List(2) = strFreightperkgAll_InCol:
Freight_Str_PerKg_List(3) = strFreightless45All_InCol:
Freight_Str_PerKg_List(4) = strFreightgreater45All_InCol:
Freight_Str_PerKg_List(5) = strFreight100All_InCol:

' this goes until (9)

For a = 1 To 3
For b = 1 To 3
For D = 1 To 9

If Freight_Str_Minimum_List(a) = 0 Then GoTo nextsegment3
If Freight_Col_Minimum_List(b) = 0 Then GoTo nextsegment3
If Freight_Col_PerKg_List(D) = 0 Then GoTo nextsegment3


'lines of code with calculations With...end with

nextsegment3:
Next a
Next b
Next D
```

Comment: but the debug error doesn't stop in that code line. It is after it gets to nextsegment3. What would be another option you could recommend? I want the calculations to not occur if e.g. freight_col_perkg_list(8) does not exist in the sheet.

Comment: Just use `Next` and drop the `a`, `b`, and `D`... but you've got the order backwards, it should be `D`, `b`, `a`. Proper indentation would help you realize this btw.

Comment: the reverse d, B, a    in connection with     If Freight_Str_Minimum_List(a) = "" Then GoTo nextsegment3 was the correct solution. dropping a,b,d causes an error. thanks for the help @BigBen .. (we are all learning, some are at the beginning of learning code and some are masters)

Comment: Could you remove the Gotos If you use `<> 0` in the If ?

Comment: If Freight_Str_Minimum_List(a) <> 0 Then .. what would then follow?

Comment: In that case you would break the `If` statement into multiple lines instead of putting the `Then` part all on the same line. Using `GoTo` is very bad practice and should always be avoided when possible. (And 99% of the time it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

No `Goto`:

```vb
For a = 1 To 3
    For b = 1 To 3
        For D = 1 To 9
        
            If Freight_Str_Minimum_List(a) <> 0 Then 
                If Freight_Col_Minimum_List(b) <> 0 Then 
                   If Freight_Col_PerKg_List(D) <> 0 Then 
                       'lines of code with calculations With...end with
                   End If
                End If
            End If
 
        Next D
    Next b
Next a
```